# Deadlock when creating a materialized view

Tags: oracle, deadlock, materialized-views

I am trying to create a materialized view in oracle (with sql developer).

I have tested it on a small table and everything went ok.

Now i am doing it on a very big table, and after some hour of elaboration i get the following error:
"ORA-04020: deadlock detected while trying to lock"

Is there a way to avoid it? Or can't do much since the table is too big?

Comment: a query would help along with some stats from query execution log

Comment: sorry but i'm not very experienced... what's a query execution log? where can i find it?

Comment: http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/376.tracing-sql-statement-execution also use excution plan https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_genplan.htm#TGSQL95114

Answer (score 1):

Something else in your database has an object locked that your query needs in order to be built.

To find out which object try;

```
SELECT vo.object_id, obj.object_name, vo.oracle_username, vo.os_user_name, vo.session_id
  FROM v$locked_object vo
       INNER JOIN all_objects obj
       ON vo.object_id = obj.object_id
```

Look for objects that your materialized view will be trying to use and you should see which user has the object locked.

Go to the user and ask them to commit or rollback whatever they are doing.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Does that mean that for all the time in which oracle tries to create the MV, nobody can work on the source table? That might be a big problem...

Comment: Well i assume that if someone does a select on my table, it does not lock it, but if he updates some row on the table instead it does. Then i have a big problem since the MV creation will take hours, and in that time someone will for sure lock the table at some time. Is there anything i can do?